# Restrict API + for specific range of IP

Tags: node.js

I have to restrict my APIs to Specific range of IPs. For a single IP i done the following:

```
exports.IPCheck = function(req, res, next){
    var ip = req.ip || 
             req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
             req.connection.remoteAddress || 
             req.socket.remoteAddress ||
             req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;

     // Your allowed ip. You can also check against an array
     console.log(ip);     
    if(ip == '::ffff:127.0.0.1'){  ------> have to check for Range of IPs.
       next();
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
        res.send(JSON.stringify({"Message":"Permission denied for IP " + ip}));
    }
}
```

I have to check for Range of IPs. Whether i have to do `regularexpression` do find out the range?? Please provide your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't say what range you want to check for, but you probably need to parse the first couple parts of the IP address (there are presumably modules that already can do this for you), convert to numbers and then use numeric comparisons.  You may have to be prepared for both ipv4 and ipv6 forms of addresses.

Answer (score 0):

IP4 is basically 32 bit and represented in 4 different section. So you can convert it to no and it will be easy to compare. Same way IP6 is 128 bit convert it to number and compare it.

Comment: Thanks. can you provide some coding samples??

Comment: I dont have code sample but this might be useful https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip-to-int you can get code from GitHub for module.